# Why is this not a function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, real-numbers

This problem is from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications
[image]

This is the definition that the book gave of function
[image]

Here is my work so far 
[image]

It's pretty clear to me that 1b and 1c are not functions because in each case one element of R is not assigned exactly one element of R( sqrt(x) -> +sqrt(x) and -sqrt(x) ).   Why is 1a not a function though? For the ones I tried, a unique element of R was assigned to another unique element of R (4->1/4,  3-> 1/3). In the explanation, would it be possible to give each R a subscript, like you're mapping from R1 to R2? I feel like R to R is kind of confusing. I understand why the author chose not to use the subscripts though - real is the same as real

Comment: $0\in\mathbb{R}$, but what is $f(0)$?

Comment: It is "function", but it is *not* a "function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$."

Comment: @mapierce271 That is essentially the answer to this question

Comment: ooohhh, 0 from R is not assigned exactly another element in R

Comment: Consider the domain of each function. Is the domain $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If it is not a function from R to R but it generally is a function, what is the definition of a function then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: a) consider what happens at $f(0)$.

b) What happens to $f(x)$ when $x<0$?

Comment: oh for b and c, there's two reasons for why it is not a function - two outputs(square root) and for some values of x, x cannot even be mapped?

Comment: @committedandroider No, the square root does not assign two values for each input. The domain of the square root function is the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x \geq 0\}$, and so is the output (image) set.

Comment: @committedandroider the square root assigns one output but is not in the real domain (for b). E.g. consider $f(-1)$ = $\sqrt(-1)=i$. Ignore my comment for part c, I didn't spot the +/-, the function is multi-valued as you say.

Comment: Oh so the whole idea of a function is that each possible input matches to exactly one output(in the domain as well)

Comment: @committedandroider the input must have exactly one output. But two unique inputs can be mapped to the same output (my mistake in the comment).

Comment: @committedandroider Yes, such a function is called injective, or one-to-one. However, that is not of concern for the problem at hand. The functions are not functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, because the domain of each function is not $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: When you mean output set, do you mean codomain, or image? -http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/domain-range-codomain.html